# Finding the equation of the plane of a Tetrahedron.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the boundaries in order to evaluate a triple integral of a tetrahedron. The points are $(0,0,0)$,$(1,1,0)$,$(1,0,0)$ and $(1,0,1)$. I have found some questions here, but no one applies to my case. I need help too, to find the equation of the plane with intercepts, and I tried to use the example of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIt1cn21EaU),but my tetrahedron seems to have something particular.

Below there is a plotting of the vertices of this tetrahedron.
[image]

Comment: The intersection of the "diagonal" plane $\Pi$ and the $xy$-plane the line that passes through $(0, 0, 0)$ and $(1, 1, 0)$, namely, $x = y$, $z = 0$, so the plane has the form $x - y + a z = 0$ for some $a$. On the other hand, considering the intersection of $\Pi$ with the $xz$ plane gives that $\Pi$ has the form $x + b y - z = 0$ for some $b$, and hence $\Pi$ is $x - y - z = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT.

The equation of the plane passing through points $P$, $Q$ and $R$ is
$$
(P\times Q+Q\times R+R\times P)\cdot\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}=(P\times Q)\cdot R.
$$

Comment: This does not answer his question completely, please elaborate on if he asks for particular case @Aretino

Comment: @DarkKnight That was only a hint: the OP could have asked for more, but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The plane you are looking for intersects the plane $z=0$ along the line $x=y$. Therefore it has an equation of the form $z=c(x-y)$, $c$ a constant. Plugging in the point $(1,0,1)$ leads to $c=1$, so that you finally obtain the equation $z=x-y$.

Comment: But point (1,0,0) does not lie on the region which you found @Christian Blatter

Comment: @DarkKnight: The plane $z=x-y$ forms the "roof"  of the tetrahedron $T$. The "base" of $T$ in the $(x,y)$-plane $z=0$ is the triangle $0\leq y\leq x\leq1$.